# How do I do a left outer join on an array?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am having trouble doing a left outer join with a jsonb array involved.

My schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cusips (
  name TEXT,
  cusip TEXT,
  ticker TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS companies (
  name TEXT,
  data JSONB
);
```

My query:

```
INSERT INTO cusips (name, cusip, ticker) VALUES
  ('Berkshire Official', '90210', 'BRKA'),
  ('Apple Corp', '90211', 'AAPL'),
  ('Microsoft Company', '90212', 'MSFT');

INSERT INTO companies (name, data) VALUES
  ('Berkshire', '{"tickers": ["BRKA", "BRKB"]}'),
  ('Apple', '{"tickers": ["AAPL"]}'),
  ('Microsoft', '{"tickers": ["MSFT"]}');

SELECT * FROM (SELECT name, cusip, ticker FROM cusips) c,
  LATERAL (
   SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data->'tickers') AS ticker
   FROM companies
   WHERE ticker::TEXT = 'BRKA'
  ) cc
WHERE c.cusip = '90210'
```

This query returns:

```
name        cusip   ticker  ticker
Berkshire   90210   BRKA    "BRKA"
Berkshire   90210   BRKA    "BRKB"
Berkshire   90210   BRKA    "AAPL"
Berkshire   90210   BRKA    "MSFT"
```

I would like one row, with the name, cusip, and all the data for the company (in this case it would just be the tickers)...e.g.:

```
name        cusip   data
Berkshire   90210   {"tickers": ["BRKA", "BRKB"]}
```

EDIT: While I could join on the company name the names are oftentimes different between the tables so I must join on the ticker.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fa376/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just want a simple `JOIN` between the tables:

```
SELECT c.name, c.cusip, cc.data
FROM cusips c
JOIN companies cc ON cc.name= c.name
WHERE c.cusip = '90210'
```

Output:

```
name        cusip   data
Berkshire   90210   {"tickers": ["BRKA", "BRKB"]}
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0ad3c/2)

If you have to match on the tickers because the `name` columns may not match for some reason, you can use [`@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) operator to check if the ticker exists in the `tickers` array:

```
SELECT c.name, c.cusip, cc.data
FROM cusips c
JOIN companies cc ON cc.data->'tickers' @> to_jsonb(c.ticker)
WHERE c.cusip = '90210'
```

Output:

```
name        cusip   data
Berkshire   90210   {"tickers": ["BRKA", "BRKB"]}
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0ad3c/24)

Comment: The names between my cusips table and companies table will oftentimes be different for various reasons. Need to do a join on the tickers. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @user72840184 see my edit - that will match on the tickers

Answer (score 2):

Nick's answer seems like the sanest answer.  If for some reason you wanted to deconstruct the JSON and reconstruct it, you could use:

```
SELECT c.name, c.cusip, c.ticker, 
       jsonb_build_object('tickers', jsonb_agg(cc.ticker))
FROM cusips c CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(co.data->'tickers') AS ticker
      FROM companies co
      WHERE co.name = c.name
     ) cc
WHERE c.cusip = '90210'
GROUP BY c.name, c.cusip, c.ticker;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dd519e2188215ef23affc82b8b094520) is the corresponding db<>fiddle.